# The setFunction in R.matlab library isn't executing properly?

Tags: r, matlab

```
code1 <- c(
  "function [y]=func(x)",
  "fprintf('its working! \n');",
  "y=x;",
  "end"
)

x<-10
setFunction(matlab,code1)
evaluate(matlab,"[y] = func(x);")
z <- getVariable(matlab,c("y"))
```

Error:
Error in throw.default("MatlabException: ", lasterr) :
MatlabException: Failed to evaluate expression '[y] = func(x);'

Version of R: 4.0.5

Version of Matlab: R2021a

Comment: what is `matlab` in the code

Comment: but your code says `matlab` instead of `R.matlab`

Comment: 'library(R.matlab)

Matlab$startServer()

matlab <- Matlab()

isOpen <- open(matlab)'    

matlab is a package from R: 'R.matlab'

Comment: I believe you need to pass `x` to matlab using `setVariable`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works without the `sprintf` which is returning an error:

```
library(R.matlab)

# Start server
Matlab$startServer(port = 9997)

# Connect to server
matlab <- Matlab(port = 9997); 

code <- "function [y]=func(x) 
           y=x;
         end"

x <- 10
setVariable(matlab, x = x)
setFunction(matlab,code)
evaluate(matlab,"y=func(x);")
y <- getVariable(matlab,c("y"))
y

# $y
# [,1]
# [1,]    10
# 
# attr(,"header")
# attr(,"header")$description
# [1] "MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file, Platform: PCWIN64, Created on: Fri Jun 11 22:30:39 2021                                        "
# 
# attr(,"header")$version
# [1] "5"
# 
# attr(,"header")$endian
# [1] "little"
```